# Having problem whit split Golang´s code that import C library

Tags: c, go, gcc, cgo

I wrote a code that imports the C library and works fine when all it is in one file. But when I split the code into two files, so that the function is in another file, it doesn´t work.
I run Windows 10 x64, Go 1.14 and I use TDM-GCC-64.

When I execute `go run .` it returns this problem:

```
# v0
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b001\_x008.o: in function `main':
./swemini.c:74: multiple definition of `main'; $WORK\b001\_cgo_main.o:/tmp/go-build/_cgo_main.c:1: first defined here
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b001\_x015.o: in function `main':
./swetest.c:737: multiple definition of `main'; $WORK\b001\_cgo_main.o:/tmp/go-build/_cgo_main.c:1: first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is part of the main.go

```
package main

//#cgo CFLAGS: -I C:/Go-Project/src/Astrocal
//#cgo LDFLAGS: -L C:/Go-Project/src/Astrocal -lswedll64
//#include "swephexp.h"
import "C"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    var xx [6]C.double
    var serr string
    var serr_C *C.char = C.CString(serr)
    var ret C.int32

    fmt.Printf("The OK constant is: %d\n", C.OK)

    sweSetEphePath()

...
```

functions.go

```
package main

func sweSetEphePath() {
    C.swe_set_ephe_path(C.CString("C:/sweph/ephe"))
}
```

I've already tried importing the C library into one or the other file, and simultaneously as well. It indicates the same problem.

Can you help me?

Comment: You need import "C" in functions.go

Comment: Thank you. I did it but doesn´t work too. Shows the same problem.